# dynamically remove the divs that are added earlier dynamically

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function to insert divs dynamically into the web page. but then I have to remove these divs. While adding the divs I used a classname to all the divs. So I got all the elements from the dom using getElementsByClassName() and looping through all these elements and deleting the divs. My code is not removing all the divs that were created earlier.

Please find my code snippet:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("xxxx");

for (var i = 0; i < elements .length; i++) {

  var element = elements[i];

  if (element && element.hasChildNodes()) {

      var parent_node = element.parentNode;

      while(element.firstChild) {

          parent_node.insertBefore(element.firstChild, element);
      }

      parent_node.removeChild(element);

   }

   elements = document.getElementsByClassName("xxxx");

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the last line "elements = document.getElementsByClassName("xxxx");" - that line will cause you to miss out every other element as you go around the loop.

Comment: Also the "if (element && element.hasChildNodes())" line means you'll only remove divs that have sub-elements. Is that what you mean to do?

Comment: yea my div always has child nodes or text nodes.

Comment: Hmmm. Perhaps try adding some console.log statements, or add some break points using firebug (or similar) to see what it's doing. Sorry - nothing else seems obviously wrong in your code to me...

Comment: I got the solution but its very slow. Every time I remove the div, the elements.length is changing. so, i in for loop is incrementing and length is also redused by 1. So the loop is getting through in the middle. So after I increment the i value, I am decrementing it again. Doing this does fix the problem , but the processing is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to remove all DIV elements with that class, you can use this code:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("xxxx");
while ( elements[0] ) {
    elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
}
```

It will remove your DIVs and their child nodes as well.